# Example of replacements for HTML tag <div></div>

Tags: html, accessibility, semantic-html

I am working on a project where one of the parts i am creating a "contact us" section, where it includes general information like, address, gmail, telephone number, and a different part of it is an actual form where you can type in the information. I tend to rely alot on the "div" tag even though it is not semantic. I want to clean up my code and some how replace as many of these divs as possible with more semantic tags. I have tried to search up tags to somehow replace the divs i have, but can not find tags that i can replace them with.

This is a screenshot of the footer for some context
https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2Cei.jpg

```html
        <footer>
            <section class="contact">
                <div class="content">
                    <h2>Contact Us</h2>
                    <p>
                        If you ever want to get in contact with us, or ask us 
                        a question, do not hesitate to send us a message using
                        the form below!
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="contactInfo">
                        <div class="box">
                            <div class="icon"><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i></div>
                            <div class="text">
                                <h3>Address</h3>
                                <p>5263 Fantasy Kebab Road, <br>Bergen, Norway, <br>55060</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="box">
                            <div class="icon"><i class="fas fa-phone"></i></div>
                            <div class="text">
                                <h3>Phone</h3>
                                <p>21-666-9112</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="box">
                            <div class="icon"><i class="far fa-envelope"></i></div>
                            <div class="text">
                                <h3>Email</h3>
                                <p>bigemail@gmail.com</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <form class="contactForm">
                        <h2>Send Message</h2>
                        <div class="inputBox">
                            <input type="text" name="full_name" required="required">
                            <span>Full Name</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="inputBox">
                            <input type="text" name="email" required="required">
                            <span>Email</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="inputBox">
                            <textarea required="required"></textarea>
                            <span>Type your Message...</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="inputBox">
                            <input type="submit" name="submit_button" value="Send">
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </section>
        </footer>
```

Comment: check this site to view the different tags to use
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_semantic_elements.asp

Comment: @ItsFragilis if the div belongs to a grid, would i have to count for that when choosing the semantic tag? or would i just focus on the content inside of the tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should definitely replace the divs that wrap your `input`s with `label`s.

Without labels, this is how your input fields will be read a screen reader (in these examples, I'm using Voiceover). Notice how the input is not described as *Full Name*, or anything meaningful for the user to know what should go into this input.

[image: voiceover screenshot of input field without label]

```css
label {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <section class="contact">
    <form class="contactForm">
      <h2>Send Message</h2>
      <label class="inputBox">
          <input type="text" name="full_name" required="required">
          <span>Full Name</span>
        </label>
      <label class="inputBox">
          <input type="text" name="email" required="required">
          <span>Email</span>
        </label>
      <label class="inputBox">
          <textarea required="required"></textarea>
          <span>Your Message</span>
        </label>
      <div class="inputBox">
        <input type="submit" name="submit_button" value="Send">
      </div>
    </form>
  </section>
</footer>
```

With a label element, the screen reader has a way to describe the field by the text that is inside the label -- *Full Name*.

[image: voiceover screenshot of input field with label]

---

The [`<address>` HTML element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/address) indicates that the enclosed HTML provides contact information for a person or people, or for an organization.

The [`<ul>` HTML element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul#usage_notes) is for grouping a collection of items that do not have a numerical ordering, and their order in the list is meaningless.

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<address>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <h3>Address</h3>
      <p>5263 Fantasy Kebab Road, <br>Bergen, Norway, <br>55060</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h3>Phone</h3>
      <a href="tel:21-666-9112">21-666-9112</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h3>Email</h3>
      <a href="mailto:bigemail@gmail.com">bigemail@gmail.com</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</address>
```

Comment: I really like this one. But is there a tag that could replace the last input box?

Comment: Are you referring to the div around the submit button? If you need it for styling purposes, it is perfectly fine for it to remain a div. If not, just delete it.

Comment: Also, is `Fantasy Kebab Road` a real place? 

Comment: i wish man haha. just said Fantasy Kebab Road because there is quite many good kebab place in bergen haha

Answer (score 2):

there are many ways of adding semantics. One way is to use html5 elements like the [address](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTML/Element/address) element for your contact information. You can also add an [anchor element](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) with `href` being `tel:[number]` or `mailto:[email]`

Sometimes you have information inside that cant be expressed with html tags but you can help a search engine understand your data better by using [json-ld](https://json-ld.org/) or [schema.org/microdata](https://schema.org/Organization#eg-0007). That could be a recipe, pagination, organisations, people, telephone number etc.

Comment: I will try it out!